# Provide two methods for same rest end-point but differs in PathVariable in Spring

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a requirement in which I need to map the request body to a particular child class based on the path variable. The request  body does not contain by itself any information as to which child class to pick.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Update Developer (dev)",
        response = ResponseEntity.class)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PATCH,
        value = "/{type}")
public ResponseEntity<Response> updateDeveloper(
        @PathVariable String type,
        @RequestParam("year") String year,
        @RequestBody Developer employeeUpdate,

) { .....}


@ApiOperation(value = "Update Manager (manager)",
        response = ResponseEntity.class)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PATCH,
        value = "/{type}")
public ResponseEntity<Response> updateManager(
        @PathVariable String type,
        @RequestParam("year") String year,
        @RequestBody Manager employeeUpdate,

) { .....}
```

Where Developer and Manager extends abstract class Employee.

I tried by having only one method like below:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Update Employee (manager, dev)",
        response = ResponseEntity.class)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PATCH,
        value = "/{type}")
public ResponseEntity<Response> updateEmployee(
        @PathVariable String type,
        @RequestParam("year") String year,
        @RequestBody Employee employeeUpdate,

) { .....}
```

But spring is unable to instantiate the Employee instance as its abstract.

Is my design incorrect? I do prefer to have a solution which doesn't require to modify the Employee/Developer/Manager classes.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You misunderstood what "REST endpoint" means. It's not "Java method that will answer", it's a "combination of Path, Method and Produced/Consumed types". What you've described looks like two REST endpoints to me. If you actually want to call common Java method, then define that method and call them from `updateDeveloper` and `updateManager`. Like you would in Java if your interface declared that those update operations are different, but implementation declared them the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for looking into this. I have found a way that suits my situation:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Update Developer (dev)",
        response = ResponseEntity.class)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PATCH,
        value = "/{type:developer}")
public ResponseEntity<Response> updateDeveloper(
        @PathVariable String type,
        @RequestParam("year") String year,
        @RequestBody Developer employeeUpdate,

) { .....}

@ApiOperation(value = "Update Manager (manager)",
        response = ResponseEntity.class)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PATCH,
        value = "/{type:manager}")
public ResponseEntity<Response> updateManager(
        @PathVariable String type,
        @RequestParam("year") String year,
        @RequestBody Manager employeeUpdate,

) { .....}
```

With this I will not get any instantiation error as well, when trying to have single method and data type of request body is set as the parent.

Answer (score 0):

By REST compliance, you should identify your resource:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PATCH, value = "/developer")

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PATCH, value = "/manager")
```

If you still want to post a body randomly (which either a developer or a manager), you a combined DTO of Manager and Developer:

```
public class EmployeeDTO {
    private int type; // Developer or manager
    // All of properties of Manager and Developer
}
```

By inspecting `type` you are able to delegate to correct service method.

Comment: You already included type in path, so `{type}` becomes unnecessary. (More than that, you'll either get 404 becuase you required type, or always get type as empty string. Don't remember which specifically).

Comment: 404 what? I think the OP want to find developers by type or manager by manager type etc...

Comment: Yes, but you already have "developer" in the path mapping, what do you need `{type}` for then? You effectively declared path `/developer/<something>` here. And I would expect that normally you don't call REST using URI like `/developer/developer`, nor should anyone write a REST API like that.